# How can I increase number of concurrent requests in a Databricks cluster?

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

## Context

We have a dashboard in our application that has 8 widgets on initial load. Each widgets makes an API call to our Django backend, and each of those opens up a JDBC connection to a Databricks Cluster and runs a SQL query.

The issue that we are witnessing is that only 4 queries are able to run concurrently while the other 4 has to wait for any of the first 4 to finish before running.

Cluster Configuration

Databricks Runtime Version: 11.3 LTS

Worker Type:  r6i.xlarge min 2 workers max 16 workers

Driver Type: r6i.2xlarge

We tried to modify a couple spark configurations with no luck

```
spark.databricks.io.cache.enabled true
spark.databricks.maxConcurrentRuns 100
spark.default.parallelism 20
spark.databricks.cluster.profile serverless
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions 20
```

Comment: have you considered using serverless sql for this workload?

Comment: Yup that is the plan within the next few months. Currently the switch over is blocked by migrating the system to use Unity. 

One question related to serverless sql. What kind of improvements would serverless be able to offer in this scenario?